# Focus on input field cause issue related with Safari bottom navigation bar

Tags: html, css, ios, angular, safari

[image: Before focus on input it is appearing normally like this.]

and after focusing on input it becoming like this

[image]

Some strange blue part is appearing under input field. It happening only on iphone devices on safari browser.

How can I solve this issue?
which parts can cause this?